# How to use urlmanager yii2 with controller/detail?alias=abc-xyz

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, config, yii-url-manager

I have problem with alias on URL.

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I try use with config

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<alias:\w+>'=>'controller/action',
```

but URL still access with link

```
controller/detail?alias=abc-xyz
```

Not access link

```
controller/detail/abc-xyz
```

I don't understand why.

please help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Regex shorthand character `\w` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]` so as you see there is no single `-` here (well, there is but for ranges only which is different thing). Read more about regex at [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

Modify your rule like this:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<alias:[\w\-]+>'=>'controller/action',
```

Comment: Thanks so much, This rule need change to :
`'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<alias:[\w\-]+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',`